# Order By Date desc evaluates 01-01-1970 higher then everything else

Tags: postgresql, date, sql-order-by

I have the following simplified query

```
SELECT 
   id
   to_char(execution_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as execution_date
FROM schema.values
ORDER BY execution_date DESC, id DESC
```

execution_date can be null.

If no value is present in execution_date it will be set to 1970-01-01 as default. My problem is, that the following table values will lead to a result where 1970-01-01 is treated as the newest date.

Table:

| id | execution_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | 2022-01-02 |
| 4 |  |

Result I would expect

| id | execution_date |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 4 | 1970-01-01 |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 |

What I get

| id | execution_date |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1970-01-01 |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 |
| 3 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 |

How can I get the correct order and is it possible to easily return an empty varchar if the date is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5d1fc31a3cf2d3121092f2446cce87e5

```
SELECT 
   id,
   to_char(coalesce( execution_date, '1970-01-01'::date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as execution_date
FROM values1
ORDER BY execution_date DESC, id DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you table has NULL values, not empty values, you can try to use **`nulls last`** :

```
with t as (select 1 as id, NULL::date as dt
union select
2, '2020-01-01'::date
union select
3, '2020-01-02'::date
union select
4, NULL::date)
select * 
from t
order by t.dt desc nulls last, id desc;
```

[image]

It should work for an empty text values also:

```
with t as (select 1 as id, ''::text as dt
union select
2, '2020-01-01'::text
union select
3, '2020-01-02'::text
union select
4, NULL::text)
select * 
from t
order by t.dt desc nulls last, id desc
```

[image]

And if you need to change your NULL date to 1970 just use **`COALESCE()`** :

```
with t as (select 1 as id, NULL::date as dt
union select
2, '2020-01-01'::date
union select
3, '2020-01-02'::date
union select
4, NULL::date)
select coalesce(t.dt, '1970-01-01'::date) as dt
from t
order by t.dt desc nulls last, id desc
```

[image]

Here's the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e2b96c5f049f2a733679fb43a95f42e0)

Comment: Thanks - but this looks a bit to static, right?

Comment: Probable I wasn't little unclear about "static", but here the standard language construction is used with a predictable result. Let me know if I can answer something more detailed for my case (:

Comment: @Jesusbrother: the trick is to use `order by ... desc nulls last` and make sure you sort by the column, not the expression. `order by t.dt` will sort by the actual column value. `order by dt` will sort by the value of the `coalesce` expression. It's more obvious if you choose a column alias that is different than the column name. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e8c695c276cc5dbd970d84fd9d801323

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wew, I understand what you are talking about. It is really bad practice to give aliase name similar to the column name (especially in MySQL due to possibility of using aliases in WHERE). In my case I just did it coz I was too lazy to come up with a new name, and I sorry for that ;) Thank you for bringing attention on this thing!

Comment: @Jesusbrother: I actually meant that comment to be for codlix :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not to see the forest for the trees...

Here is the simple solution:

```sql
SELECT 
   id
   CASE WHEN execution_date IS NULL THEN ''
            ELSE to_char(execution_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') END 
            AS execution_date
FROM schema.values
ORDER BY execution_date DESC, id DESC
```